# Node cannot find the start module

Tags: node.js

I am trying to set-up a very simple test with node. To do so, I have created the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "name": "course-43",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple test",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Then I have installed the dependencies with "npm install" and I have executed the "node start" command which outputs the following error:

```
$ node start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\[...]\Course-43\start'
?[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m {
  code: ?[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'?[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

The `node start` command is executed in the same directory as my package.json file.

Can someone help me to understand why node.js is trying to load a file instead of the script in my `package.json` file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `npm start` instead of `node start`. If you want to use `node` directly, then you should use `node index.js`. But the `npm start` option will do the same in this case

Comment: That's it ! Thanks for your help.